# how to make yo angular load bootstrap theme css

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman, yo

`yo angular` install bootstrap files all fine. The `index.html` file looks like this at the moment:

```
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This doesn't include `bootstrap.theme.css` file.

What is the recommended way of adding this? Do I manually go in there and add it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to do it is override you bower.json file to load bootstrap dependencies, and then run `grunt wiredep`

The `bower.json` would look like this:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "json3": "^3.3.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.1.5",
    "raty": "~2.7.0",
    "kineticjs": "~5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.3.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
      ]        
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/965#issuecomment-68548259

Answer (score 3):

Do the following

```
bower install bootstrap-css --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it manually below the other `.css` include if it's locally available on your system (e.g. in `bower_components/`).

If the file is not locally available I'd add it right above the `<!-- Place favicon.ico ... -->` otherwise it might break your `grunt build` and/or `grunt serve` because of `bower` trying to minify the file.

The same goes with Google Font imports, place them above the `<!-- Place favicon.ico ... -->` otherwise `bower` will try to minify it (under `htmlmin` options in `Gruntfile.js`).

[Here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/361)  you can read some more about the subject.